# Can anyone give me the common name of this flower/vine?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Photo taken in NYC in April 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is *[Kerria japonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerria_japonica)* (L.) DC, in it's less common non-filled form.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is *[Rosa foetida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_foetida)*, the yellow rose. Unfortunately the leafs are not visible very well but the flower, together with the growth, is pretty characteristic. See this image (from [here](http://www.ludwigsroses.co.za/gallery/roses_in_persia/)) for comparision:

[image]

The German Wikipedia also has a drawing of the plant (from [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelbe_Rose)):

[image]